# Bootstrap datepicker dropdown as 100% of input

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

I am currently working on a project where I am in need of a calendar that will be 100% of the HTML input that it is based on. I know that you can resize the calendar based on pixels with the following

```
 .datepicker {
   /*This has to be 100% of the width of the textinput*/
   width: "n"px;
 }

 .table-condensed {
   width: 100%;
 }
```

Based on HTML that looks as following

```
 <div class = "input-group date" id='datepicker'>
      <span class = "input-group-addon"><i class = "fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
      <input class = "form-control" type="text" name="date" id = "date" placeholder="DD/MM-ÅÅÅÅ"
      <?php 
      if(isset($_SESSION['searchDate'])){
        $displaySearch = $_SESSION['searchDate'];
        unset($_SESSION['$searchDate']);
      }
      ?>
      value = "<?php echo $displaySearch;?>">
    </div>
```

I have searched all over the internet without finding an answer. Note that there is jQuery to initialize the datepicker

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    format: "dd/mm-yyyy",
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true,
    clearBtn: true,
    orientation: "top",
    language: 'sv',
    weekStart: 1,
  });
});
```

My assumption is that in some way need to have the input surrounded in some div where I then have the input as 100% of the div but that does not work for me. Anyone of you people encountered this problem before and found a legitimate solution?

Comment: let me clarify. you want your form to shrink and expand depending on how short/long the word that the user is typing?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following snippet. I have commented in the code. For more information visit their documentation

https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

```js
$(function() {
  $("#datePicker").datepicker({
    // Here you can add any additional parameters
    format: "yyyy/mm/dd"
  });
});
```

```html
<!--Importing CDN's-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

<!--DatePicker component-->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class='col-sm-6'>
      <input type='text' class="form-control" id='datePicker' placeholder="yyyy/mm/dd" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have linked the wrong picker, the linked one is from Eonasdan and the one on the codes is from eternicode.

Comment: So this doesn't solve the question? You want the exact datepicker?

Comment: If you link other picker which doesn't initialize of the same way It will throw error, nor their option/documentation will probably be the same

Comment: Can you share the link of the documentation, of the datepicker you are using? Btw you need the same input like in my answer from that datepicker right?

Comment: This is the one that should be used (for the code provided in this answer): https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: thanks for sharing and noticing the exact bootstrap date picker :) will have a look